# ics file not imported correctly on iOS

Tags: ios, icalendar

my software generates ics files. When i have an event that takes place over several days i use an reoccurring event with possible exception for the time on the first and last date. In MS Outlook, the file can be imported and everything works fine. But if you import it on an iPhone/iPad, it doesn't display the times correctly.  Here is an example of a file. The event is from 18th Mar to 21st Mar 9:00-17:00 except that first day starts at 10:00 and last day ends at 15:00

What does the iOS Calendar do differently? How can i make it compatible?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 1.0.1//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
LAST-MODIFIED:20230104T023643Z
TZURL:https://www.tzurl.org/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Berlin
X-PROLEPTIC-TZNAME:LMT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+005328
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:18930401T000000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19160430T230000
RDATE:19400401T020000
RDATE:19430329T020000
RDATE:19460414T020000
RDATE:19470406T030000
RDATE:19480418T020000
RDATE:19490410T020000
RDATE:19800406T020000
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19161001T010000
RDATE:19421102T030000
RDATE:19431004T030000
RDATE:19441002T030000
RDATE:19451118T030000
RDATE:19461007T030000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19170416T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19180415T010000Z;BYMONTH=4;BYDAY=3MO
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19170917T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19180916T010000Z;BYMONTH=9;BYDAY=3MO
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19440403T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19450402T010000Z;BYMONTH=4;BYDAY=1MO
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEMT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
DTSTART:19450524T020000
RDATE:19470511T030000
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19450924T030000
RDATE:19470629T030000
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19460101T000000
RDATE:19800101T000000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19471005T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19491002T010000Z;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19800928T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;UNTIL=19950924T010000Z;BYMONTH=9;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19810329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19961027T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20240305T142917Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20240318T090000
SUMMARY:text
SEQUENCE:28494149
UID:053
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body><h3>Title</h3><h4>Details zur Ver
 anstaltung</h4>text...</body></html>
TRANSP:OPAQUE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
ORGANIZER;CN="Mustermann, Max":MAILTO:max@mustermann.de
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20240321T080000
DURATION:PT8H
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-P1D
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20240305T142917Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20240321T090000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20240321T150000
SUMMARY:text
SEQUENCE:28494149
UID:053
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body><h3>Title</h3><h4>Details zur Ver
 anstaltung</h4>text...</body></html>
TRANSP:OPAQUE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
ORGANIZER;CN="Mustermann, Max":MAILTO:max@mustermann.de
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20240321T090000
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20240305T142917Z
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20240318T100000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20240318T170000
SUMMARY:text
SEQUENCE:28494149
UID:053
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<html><body><h3>Title</h3><h4>Details zur Ver
 anstaltung</h4>text...</body></html>
TRANSP:OPAQUE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
ORGANIZER;CN="Mustermann, Max":MAILTO:max@mustermann.de
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20240318T090000
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: this seems to be a problem of iOS 17.4 only